# What is the derivative of the floor function?

Tags: derivatives, ceiling-and-floor-functions

What is the derivative of the following equation?

$$f(x) = \left \lfloor \frac{c}{x} \right \rfloor$$

- $c,x$ are positive integers, and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.

Does the floor function play any role here? Will it be equal to the floor of the derivative?

Comment: Note that you have specified that both $c$ and $x$ are integers. In this case, the domain is discrete. Do you think the derivative is meaningful in such cases?

Comment: @MPW sorry, what is domain and what is discrete?

Comment: Domain of $f$ is the set of values for which $f$ is defined.  Discrete means it is a set of isolated points with gaps between. Derivative only makes sense on dense set.

Answer (score 7):

$f'(x) = \begin{cases} \text{not differentiable}&\text{if }  x=\frac cn \text{ for some positive integer }n, \\
         0&\text{othewise.}\end{cases}$

Hint: Just do it by the definition of the derivative. (It is not difficult, so I omit the proof.)

Comment: The question is about the floor effect. Can you explain why do you think it will have no effect?

Comment: @Ilya Have you plotted this function? It should be fairly clear that it is composed of flat bits (with derivative $0$) and discontinuities (with no derivative) from a graph.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Sorry,I don't get your point. what you means "have no effect".$f(x)=\frac cx$ is defferentiable everywhere on $(0,\infty )$ but floor function not.

Comment: why floor is not deferential? And in the areas that it is deferential, will it provide the same result as if I apply it after the deferential?

Answer (score 3):

As Syuizen points out, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is not differentiable as a function.

However, as a *distribution*, you can write the derivative of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ as an infinite sum of [Dirac delta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \lfloor x \rfloor = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \delta_n(x).$$